# Changing footnotes to display symbols doesn't work in non English documents?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, polyglossia, hebrew, footmisc

I am using Latex for my university assignments, and I noticed something weird when I tried to include footnotes in my document.

My university's primary language is Hebrew; therefore, most of my assignments are in Hebrew. I compile my documents using XeLatex and use the [polyglossia](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia?lang=en) package to set the language and font.

I wanted to make the footnotes use symbols instead of numbers using the command `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`. When I tried it, it didn't work: the footnotes were still numbered with numbers. After experimenting, I found that putting this command after `begin{document}` causes it to work properly, so I tried to use
`\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}` instead. The reason for that is that I use a custom class file to organize my style and customizations and I'd like this command to be in this file, which is obviously loaded before `begin{document}`.

Very strangely, moving this command to the `\AtBeginDocument` block stopped it from working. The footnotes were once again numbered with numbers instead of symbols. After experimenting further, I figured out that in English documents, this problem doesn't appear at all. In an English document using `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` works both before and after `begin{document}`, which means `\AtBeginDocument` is no longer necessary. I am very confused by this: why in regular English documents I can set the footnotes to count with symbols without an issue while in Hebrew documents I am forced to do that only after `begin{document}` and even using `\AtBeginDocumnet` doesn't help.

There is another weird problem I noticed while investigating this issue that I'd like to get help with: I am using [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) for having hyperlinks in my document, and I noticed a weird issue with the footnotes links.
In the **English** document the links show up, but clicking them doesn't take you to the bottom of the page where the footnote is, while in the **Hebrew** document the links work fine, and clicking them takes you to the footnote. This happens regardless of whether or not I change the links to use symbols. So apparently, in Hebrew, I get a bug that I can't set footnotes to use symbols unless I do that after `begin{document}` while in English I get another bug that footnote hyperlinks don't work.

Another thing I should mention is that while investigating these issues I ran into the [footmisc](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc?lang=en) package which has the option to use symbols (so I don't have to use this command myself). While in English, this package works great and removes the need to write the command `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` myself, in Hebrew this package gives me errors when loading with the `perpage` and `symbol*` options (which are some nice options of the package) and loading it with the `symbol` option doesn't change the footnotes to use symbols. It seems to be subject to the same bug I faced when trying to change it myself.

I made a stripped-down version of a document (with the important settings from my custom class file copied to it) to demonstrate the issues.

The English version:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[bottom, perpage]{footmisc}

%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
%   Script=Hebrew,
%   ItalicFont=*-Regular,
%   ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
%]{Assistant}
\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{english}
%\setsansfont{Assistant}
%\setmonofont{Assistant}

\setlength{\jot}{10pt}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdftitle={HW 1},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue
}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{Student name}
\chead{HW 1}
\rhead{24/2/2023}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
Some homework assignment\footnote{This is an important footnote} with footenotes\footnote{Another footnote}.
\end{document}
```

The Hebrew version:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = he_HE
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[bottom, symbol]{footmisc}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Assistant}
\setmonofont{Assistant}

\setlength{\jot}{10pt}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={שם הסטודנט},
    pdftitle={תרגיל בית 1},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue
}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{שם הסטודנט}
\chead{תרגיל בית 1}
\rhead{24/2/2023}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
זהו תרגיל הבית הראשון\footnote{זו הערה חשובה} ויש בו הערות שוליים\footnote{הערה נוספת}.
\end{document}
```

Note that for the Hebrew version, you need to have the [Assistant font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant) installed on your system (on Windows it may need to be installed as admin) since the default Latex font doesn't support Hebrew. Both files should be compiled with XeLatex and other than the top piece of code to set the language and font (and the text in different languages, of course) both files are identical. On my system (Windows 11 with TexStudio), both files demonstrate the bugs I described: In English, footnote symbols work, but links don't and in Hebrew, the symbols don't work but the links do.

If anyone could help me solve these bugs and get both of these functions to work in both languages, I'd really appreciate it. If you could also explain why the `footmisc` package doesn't work in Hebrew it would be nice (although not a priority since I can use symbols without this package too).

Comment: don't put two questions in one question. That is only confusing. Use this hook to change the footnote code (polyglossia is using it to setup language stuff, and as it is after the begindocument hook, it wins): `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}`.

Comment: and generally: give hyperref a chance and load it late. If I move it directly before the hypersetup the footnote links work.

Comment: The `etoolbox` package has `\AfterEndPreamble{}` which executes following `\AtBeginDocument{}`. Maybe put your symbolic footnote code there.

Comment: @rallg I tried it already. Doesn't help.